# What book drops from Demons?

Tags: terraria

I finally arrived in hell (deep underground) for the first time. When I arrived there i fought two demons, separated by a thin layer of ash blocks.

Even though it didn't do much damage, I attacked them repeatedly with the viletorn, and finally one died.

As the loot fell, my mouse was on it, and I saw an item that seemed to be called: Book of Demon in orange text.

Was I just imagining things? I tried to jump down, but was quite too high and died on falling without reaching the book. Can someone tell me if a book like that really exists?

Comment: Hello Eric, and welcome to Gaming.Stackexchange! I have taken the liberty of cleaning up your post to make it more readable.

Answer (score 15):

The [Demon Scythe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Scythe) is a rare spellbook that was released with the Terraria 1.0.5 patch. It has a roughly 2% chance of dropping from any slain demons.

So your find was quite rare! If you've not yet exited the game world, I'd suggest going back posthaste, as that's a great spell, and very worth a couple of deaths trying to get it!

Answer (score 0):

They aren't too hard to get again. Just go down with a [Musket](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Musket) and a good sword and go to town!

The [Demon Scythe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Scythe) is a really good weapon combined with [Meteor Armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteor_Armor).  It does about 40 damage.